# Integration of differential given as one-form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, front-end, evaluation, notebooks

I would like to use the integration symbol in more general way, that means to integrate any differential, like
`\[DifferentialD]y = a x^2 \[DifferentialD]x`
and then
 `\[Integral]\[DifferentialD]y`
I would expect to obtain
`(a x^3)/3`
but I get
just  `y`

Comment: Redefining internal symbols seems a really bad idea. Choose an unused symbol or name for your purpose.

Comment: I know. I'd like to use it in presentation for students, and the integration symbol is the most natural. Using a function or another symbol looses the explanatory power.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `` Notation` `` package:

```
<< Notation`

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "y_"}]] ⟺ 
     ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"d", "[", "y_", "]"}]]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"∫", "expr_"}]] ⟺ 
     ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"int", "[", "expr_", "]"}]]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox["∫", "a_", 
             "b_"], "expr_"}]] ⟺ ParsedBoxWrapper[
       RowBox[{"int", "[", RowBox[{"expr_", ",", 
               RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"a_", ",", "b_"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]]]
```

[image]

Then define

```
int[expr_ dx_d] := Integrate[expr, dx[[1]]]

int[expr_ dx_d, {x0_, x1_}] := Integrate[expr, {dx[[1]], x0, x1}]
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
\[DifferentialD]y = a x^2 \[DifferentialD]x;
∫\[DifferentialD]y
```

[image]

```
$Assumptions = h > 0;

\[DifferentialD]y = (k h λ )/(x^2 + h^2)^(3/2) \[DifferentialD]x;

\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(-∞\), \
\(∞\)]\(\[DifferentialD]y\)\)
```

[image]

This isn't the end. We can further define

```
$independentvar = x;
d[expr : Except@$independentvar] := D[expr, $independentvar] d[$independentvar]
```

Now we can do something like

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(x1\), \(x2\)]\(\[DifferentialD]Cos[x]\)\)
(* -Cos[x1] + Cos[x2] *)
```

[image]

Comment: pretty good, thanks,
 I completely  forgot about Notation package. But have question: would it be simpler define ```int[..]``` by: 
```int[exp_ d[x_] ] := Integrate[exp /. d[x] -> 1, x]```
it also works

Comment: @sebqas `/. d[x] -> 1` can be taken away. :) Thx for pointing out, I simplified the code. (I use the pattern `dx_d` because of the additional `d[expr : Except@$independentvar] :=….`, if you don't need this feature, then `int[exp_ d[x_] ] := Integrate[exp, x]` is of course better. )

Answer (score 0):

I have found some solution. It works quite well, it merely requires  to specify what is the true integration variable:

```
Unprotect[Integrate]
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(a_\), \(b_\)]\(int_\\\[DifferentialD]y_[x_]\)\) :=  Integrate[int \[DifferentialD]y /.\[DifferentialD]x -> 1, {x, a, b}]
Protect[Integrate]
```

For example, the  electric field differential due to charged rod is:

```
\[DifferentialD]E = (k  h \[Lambda] \[DifferentialD]x)/(x^2 + h^2)^(3/2)
```

and the integral for the infinite rod:

```
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \\(\[Infinity]\)]\(\[DifferentialD]E[x]\)\)
```

gives correct result:

```
(2 k \[Lambda])/h
```